# Android Circular Gallery or listview with zoom in and out option

Tags: java, android, listview, gallery

I want a list or gallery that scroll circularly and also current item must zoom in and other item must zoom out....... as below.

[image]

Can any one provide good idea to implement and also any code help...

Comment: **[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx)** might be useful for you.

Comment: Oops! Bit late to post and posted same as you

Comment: Thank you friends.. i will try and let you know what happened..