# Displaying ImageButtons in an Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I want to display ImageButtons [like](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) in an activity in my android application.

Now when i click on any one of the ImageButton, it should start a new Activity.

I don't know whether this type of view is possible or not. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you,

```
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html
```

Also this one

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116825/android-circular-gallery-or-listview-with-zoom-in-and-out-option/5116945#5116945
```

Comment: I had gone through Cover-Flow Widget. But I want to develop a gallery view like mentioned in the link....

Comment: Problem solved using this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116825/android-circular-gallery-or-listview-with-zoom-in-and-out-option/5116945#5116945
)..Thanks again....

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget.

Comment: I referred Gallery Widget. But I didnt get much stuff there. Can u please provide an example ?

Comment: You can find one example from here http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

yah that's possible.like an button clck listener there is also a listener for the image button .by that calling the another activity a

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:-

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent("<activity_class_name or intent action");

            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: But i want to display image buttons like [this] (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) 
Is it possible or not ?